# Faster assignment or check for bool values

Tags: c#, boolean, variable-assignment

The question is simple, which is faster between CalledOften1 and CalledOften2

```
    class MyTest
    {
        public bool test = false;
        void CalledOften1()
        {
            if (!test) test = true;
            DoSomething();
        }
        void CalledOften2()
        {
            test = true;
            DoSomething();
        }
    }
```

Is the compiler optimized (if possible) to avoid future assignments of test if it's already true?

**UPDATE:**
This question is just an information,  I will not use the if (bla) style if I can write test=true, I prefer code readability.

Comment: The only way to find out which one is faster is to *run it both ways* and see which one is faster. You've already written the code both ways; what is stopping you from running it?

Comment: Mh I don't know how to check required milliseconds for each job and I'm sure is faster write here for a question of this type

Comment: Well then you have a larger problem: you don't know how to successfully do a performance analysis. Unless you intend to ask the community every single time you have a performance question, my advice is to learn how to do a performance analysis. Briefly, here's how you do a performance analysis: (1) set customer-focussed performance goals, (2) write and execute realistic tests that measure application performance against those goals, (3) if you haven't met your goal, learn to use a profiler to find the slowest thing. (4) fix it. (5) go back to step (2).

Comment: If what you want to know is which is faster, but you don't know how to use a high performance timer, then you could (1) learn to use a high performance timer, or (2) write a loop that runs the code a billion times; sit there with a stopwatch waiting for it to complete, and then divide the resulting number of seconds by a billion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I prefer to measure for these sorts of questions rather than guess:

- CalledOften1: 52 million operations per second
- CalledOften2: 53 million operations per second

So they are nearly the same. If anything, the simpler method is also the faster.

Comment: Um.   How exactly did you measure the number of operations?    52 million vs. 53 million?!?

Comment: @warriorpostman: One way to do it is to run in a loop 100,000,000 times and see how long it takes. Divide 100,000,000 by the number of seconds to get the executions per second. In the tests I did I also did some warm-up loops first. I suspect that the majority of the time is spent testing the loop condition and incrementing the loop variable.

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect example of premature optimization.

If you want to set `test` to `true` every time, just set it.  Don't complicate your code for a theorized speedup.

That being said, the reduced instruction set of the second example, along with being *simpler* and more *maintainable*, is most likely faster due to avoiding the branching and reducing the number of instructions.  A single assignment of a `bool` is a very fast operation.  If you really need to know how much faster it may be, I would profile this yourself.  However, I suspect that either would be fast enough in any case.

Answer (score 2):

I would expect the second version to be slightly faster, given that it doesn't involve *any* branching. It also expresses the intention of "make sure the variable is true, whatever it was before" more clearly IMO. However:

- I doubt that it's significant
- Any number of actual changes in context could make the results change (including your code, or the version of the framework you're running against)
- Write the clearest code first, and optimize later
- Benchmark this against your real code, under realistic conditions before you decide to change anything

Comment: How did you manage to answer so fast?please tell me the secret! I know it's quite useless talking about optimization, was just interested about that because someone said me "writing memory in that case is slower"

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL: Several people got in answers before mine :)

Comment: @Fire-Dragon-DoL: Wouldn’t the *best* answer (whichever that happens to be, and according to whatever criteria) be the one to mark as accepted? Why the obsession with speed? :-)

Comment: I just mean that this question and its answers are going to be here for years, and a difference of one minute in posting time will be worth far less than accuracy, completeness, clarity, or even proper spelling, in determining which answer should sit up top.

Comment: @Fire:  Don't you know that Jon Skeet no longer answers questions here?  It is just a bot with very good AI!

Comment: @Jeffrey L Whitledge: I've chosen between the best answer and I came up with both Jon Skeet and warriorpostman answers (they were both fine). So I voted the one which came before, I think it's quite logic

Answer (score 1):

Compiler optimizes only something that is definite at compile time. This is changed at runtime so answer is no. Compiler could optimize if you were checking against constant. `CalledOften1` is faster, but the magnitude is so small that you would not notice. This is kind of microptimisation you should avoid.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, I would say that CalledOften2 is more optimized, as there is no logic test operation done.

In the end, if you are looking at this level of optimization, then your application will probably go as fast as it can.  Any performance gain you get out of this type of optimization will likely never be noticed by anyone.

My two cents,
Brian

Answer (score -4):

Premature optimization is the root of all evil. Use the one that expresses your intent most clearly.

(I'm guessing a read+branch is going to be more expensive than just a write, but don't really know the CLR. The important thing is that computers are increasing in speed exponentially, and programmers aren't. Algorithmic improvements in performance bottlenecks are worth exploring, barely measurable constant-time improvements for their own sake aren't.)

Comment: answer question or write to comments.